# How to desgin the spring boot profile active arugment?

Tags: spring-boot, profile

As we known that, we have some methods to set the profile, the priortity order is javaCode > commondline argument > jvm variable > os variable > config...

If I have 500 or more spring-boot-micro-services, what is the right way to set the profile variable?
The profile may be has 10 or more values such as prod/prod,sg/prod,us and others.
Thanks for your practical advise very much.

Maybe we can use template + os variable?

Answer (score 0):

We can externalize the properties file in springboot app and make use of Springboot config server.

Here, we need to create one springboot application which will act as config server. On main class give @EnableConfigServer @SpringBootApplication.
Refer to https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

You can create git repo for this, make branching based on your environments and give data/properties likewise. And deploy that particular branch on particular env, like config_UAT on UAT env.

Comment: Maybe configServer is an anwser which set the profile active state into the remote config center. But this method may be too heavy for the existing micro-services which need put the config into the config server such as some xml config and so on.